# Learning Development with raspberry Pi

Tags: software-development

I want to learn web development, android, iOS and windows phone development using a raspberryPi powered system. is it powerful enough? I wont be using emulators in the system, will plugin an external device for that. like for android, ill need java an Eclipse with addons. will they run smoothly enough??

Comment: You should use a proper desktop computer with your developer tools installed. Because SDK and Frameworks are targeted at debugging enables and consume much more RAM and CPU. iOS is best developed on a Mac because of so many things you to do to get it working proeplty on non mac. Windows apps can run the Pi using Mono .NET and Android apps.. not sure you can get them running on Linux without and Emulator.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, coding in the raspi is not that mighty since the user interface itself is not that fast.. so eclipse and addons, an fancy stuff.. better not.

I code mostly web and for that is perfect.

What I do so far, is that I set an apache and I enter using winSCP (or filezilla or something similar) then I change the codes using my desktop PC and my good and familiar editors.

For C++/Python I do the same and then through ssh (putty) I hit the compiler. That's good as long as you don't want to rely heavily on the debuger...
I know  there are methods for pipe-lining visual studio with your raspi and get it to debug your stuff but .. never tested.

as for iOS, windows phone and that things.. I dont really see why you would like to use a raspi instead of your laptop, to be honest :)